# Show dialog when you have no internet connection

Tags: android, dialog

How can I do so that when the application is opened, and has no Internet connection appear a dialog informing the connection and with a button "Ok " that when bombed closes the application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display an alert when internet connection not available in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242351/display-an-alert-when-internet-connection-not-available-in-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

Use a utility method in Utility class

**Utility class:**

```
public static boolean hasNetwork (){
    return instance.checkIfHasNetwork();
}

public boolean checkIfHasNetwork(){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService( Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
if (!Utility.hasNetwork()){
  // show dialog 
}
```

Also add permission in `Manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to check whether network is available. For further details, you can refer the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html).

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission to your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Add to your activity

```
    val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager //get ConnectiviyManager        
    val networkInfo = cm.activeNetworkInfo //get network info
    if(!networkInfo.isConnected){ //check if network is connected
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this) //create dialog builder
        builder.setMessage("Dialog message") //set dialog message
                .setTitle("Dialog title"); //set dialog title
        builder.setNeutralButton(R.string.ok, DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
            dialog.dismiss() //add Ok button, when clicked close the dialog
        })
        builder.create().show()//show dialog
    }
```

This is Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

First, declare permissions in the android manifest file to access network state.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Next, get android Connectivity manager using getSystemService.

```
(ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
 NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                  activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

If you only check is active network connection use isConnected.

Create a separate method and call this in onCreate method after setContentView